# сделать проверку на существование параметра

Tags: javascript, flow

Есть функция для рендера option в select

```
getOption = ({ value, text }: SelectOption): string => `<option value="${value}">${text}</option>`;
```

но при flow check ругается

```
Cannot coerce value to string because undefined [1] should not be coerced.
```

соответственно мне необходимо повесить дополнительную проверку на отсутствие value(indefined).

Comment: уточнить хочу это норм запись что вы  принимаете 1 аргумент но у него нет имени

Comment: просто записи вида { value, text } не валидна в js

Comment: @Саске, 1. ES6 вышел в 2015 году - давно пора почитать. 2. Тут вообще по flow вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <option value="${value}">
> ```

```
<option value="${value || ""}">
```

Comment: А чуть-чуть пояснить предложенное.

Answer (score -2):

```
const getOption = v => `<option value="${v.value}">${v.text}</option>`;

console.log(getOption({ value: 'va', text: 'txt' }));
/// <option value="va">txt</option>


getOption = ({ value, text }: SelectOption): string => `<option value="${!value ? '' : value}">${!text ? '' : text}</option>`;
```